# The file_counter is not updating when the script run, I want the file_counter to update so that a new csv file can be created

Tags: python, selenium, csv, web-scraping, web-crawler

The file_counter is not updating, I want the file_counter to update so that a new CSV file can be created once the old CSV file reaches the limit set. I want to create a CSV file automatically whenever the CSV file reach the limit set by me

```
 file_counter = 1
 data_file_exists = os.path.isfile('data'+str(file_counter)+'.csv')
 data_file = open('data'+str(file_counter)+'.csv', 'a', encoding='utf-8', newline='\n')
 writer = csv.writer(data_file, delimiter=',')
 data_f  = open('data'+str(file_counter)+'.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8', newline='\n')    
 reader = csv.reader(data_file, delimiter=',')
 count = 0
 for lines in data_f:
     count += 1
 print(count)
 while not count <= 20:
     file_counter += 1
 print(file_counter)
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a flaw in your logic.

```
while not count <= 20:
     file_counter += 1
```

should be:

```
while count <= 20:
     file_counter += 1
```

Even if you set `count` to any number with your while loop it will NOT increment file_counter at all.
Using the while loop i have given you, It will infinitely loop. If you are trying to set the limit to *20* I suggest using an if statement to check if `count` has reached the limit or not. If it has, you can create a new file.

```
If count >= 20:
    create_new_file()
```